# Merge changes from dev branch to all feature branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have multiple devs working on feature branches and I merge their PR's to dev branch. To sync this on local my current flow is to checkout on dev branch, pull the latest changes and then checkout to each feature and merge. I do this so that irrespective of what feature branch I'm on, I've changes from all features.

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
git checkout feature1
git merge dev
git checkout feature2
git merge dev
```

What I'm looking for is a way by which I can merge the changes from dev branch to all the features in one go. This might be silly as I've all feature changes on dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your developers should rebase their feature branch on the dev branch.

```sh
# Get latest dev branch commits
git checkout dev
git pull

# Switch to feature branch
git checkout feature-branch

# Do what you are asking for
git rebase dev

# As history of feature branch changed, you need to force-push it now
git push --force
```

Comment: I figured this out, but since after rebase git push doesn't work without --force I stopped using it. I'm not sure if using --force is a good idea.

Comment: For feature branches, using `git push --force` is totally okay because they are short-living, in contrast to your long living master and dev branch where you should never do this.

Comment: I think a better rule for rebasing is *rebasing is OK when all participants* (all users of the branch, i.e., all your co-workers that work on that same feature) *expect it and know how to deal with it*. For short-lived branches, there are usually only one or two people using it and as long as you both understand *how* to handle rebases, you're fine.

Comment: When a repository is completely private, so that you're the only one using both your laptop repo and the GitHub (or whatever) repo, you only need to agree with *yourself* about whether something is rebased. So it becomes trivial: rebase it if you want to, because everyone (i.e., you) agreed to that!